# quickly switching data contexts

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ado.net

So I have an ADO.NET object that I use to access a database via a data context.

I have test data in 2 separate databases with very similar schemas. I am considering creating 2 models from the 2 databases. But I'm not sure what the easiest way is to "switch" the models.

Ideally I'd like to be able to switch contexts by changing 1 line of code. The switching is just for diagnostics purposes.

Since I access this model from several methods, I can't (easily) create a static instance of the data context and then just change the model of the context at the beginning because I have to explicitly declare the type of the context in the method parameters (and then change the type every time I change the model).

Something like this:

```
(using SF_EntitiesDEV1 ctx = new SF_EntitiesDEV1()) {
    checkForStrangeStuff(ctx);
    runTests(ctx);
    checkResults(ctx);
    ... etc
}
```

Now if I want to change SF_EntititesDEV1 to SF_EntitiesDEV2 I have to change the method parameter types in every method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at using a generic repository approach, if you haven't already.  Most examples you'll find will be using the generic repo to do CRUD work, but I don't see why you couldn't use it to do the work you require.

Essentially you'd set up a class that takes a context (interface) as a parameter in it's constructor.  Then pass in the context you want to use when you instantiate the repository and call it's methods.

Have a look [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle) for a pretty good discussion of how to set up a generic repository.

Comment: Hoping for a simpler solution. *Sigh*